# I can't install pychecker on my ubuntu 21.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pychecker, ubuntu-21.04

So I'm trying to install pychecker to check a big python file my friend wanted me to check, but while trying to install pychecker using `sudo apt-get install pychecker` and `sudo apt-get install -y pychecker` and it returns `E: Unable to locate package pychecker`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pychecker` is no longer included as a package in Ubuntu and Debian because it is unmaintained: the latest version is from 2011, and that version will not work with current versions of Python. From [here](https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/packages/pychecker/-/blob/debian/master/debian/NEWS):

> Please consider moving away from Pychecker in favor of an alternative like
> Pylint [1].  Pychecker is basically unmaintained upstream.  Also, it is only
> supported for Python 2, so it will reach its end of life along with Python 2
> sometime in 2020.
>
> ...
>
> Now is the time to convert.  Pylint does everything that Pychecker used to
> do.  The main effort required is to create your new configuration file and
> weed out warnings that you want to ignore.
>
> [1] https://www.pylint.org/

Other alternatives include [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't even see that text and thought it was still available. Appreciate it a lot